# How do I get one row of data from mySQL table using php?

Tags: php, mysql, scripting

Here is an example of the current PHP code I have. I simply want to grab one row from the table, but it returns this error:

```
Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
$pathname = "C:\Users\BL\Documents\GitHub\Moozik\music";
$files = scandir($pathname);
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";

while ($files[0] == "." || $files[0] == "..") {
    array_shift($files);
}

print_r($files);
$song = $pathname . '\\' . $files[0];

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT song_path FROM song_data";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $its = $row["song_path"];
    printf($its);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Can you try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point 1 :**

```
You have mixed mysqli Object-oriented and Procedural methods...Use any one
```

**Point 2:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass); 
// Here You missed database to be selected
```

**Point 3:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // Used procedural method But Connection is by Object Oriented method
```

here is a full object oriented method

```
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT song_path FROM song_data";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $its = $row["song_path"];
            echo $its;
    }


$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

You don't even have to use while since you wanna fetch only one row. IF you wanna fetch more than one row, then you can use the while.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)
```

It will fetches the one row from result set..

Hope this will help.!

Comment: I suppose this is a start! I am now getting the following message `mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` @vignesh

Comment: Are you sure the name of the column and the table is correct ?

Comment: Really @bayblade567? I believe all of that is correct. How can I double check through the code? I only have one row of data in this table currently.

Comment: The error `mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result` means that the result is not a valid one. That means there was something wrong with the query.

Comment: How about you go to phpmyadmin and then type the query and check if it gives you the result or not...go to phpmyadmin and then SQL and then type the query and then execute..